# How can I roll back someone's entire project in github to its initial state after forking it to my local drive?

Tags: git, github, open-source

Is there way to roll back not every commit but **to the very beginning** of the project?
Then I want to step forward commit by commit and see what changes the author did?

What is workflow in this case?

Comment: The beginning commit is the root commit. A branch usually has one root. Sometimes it has more than one. You can list all the root commits of a branch by `git log --max-parents=0 <branch_name>`. If you need the commit sha only, plus `--pretty=%H`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git log | tail
```

will show the initial commits, each with commit id like below:

```
commit e73188b5512c82290a4070af4afddac20d0b981e
```

then

```
git checkout e73188b5512c82290a4070af4afddac20d0b981e
```

Git will use this commit as its current state, any files before commited will 
still exist but be considered "untracked" by git. Then you can clean the scene with:

```
git clean -fd
```

This will clean any files not in the commit state, Then you return the the state up to that commit, and through the git log list, you can reach any point you want, by checkout the adjacent commit, you can view the changes. Or you can see the different in git with:

```
git diff  commit-id1 commit-id2
```

Comment: how do u copy those commit ids? they look nasty, or i have to start typing the first letters-numbers of the id - and the rest of the id' name will pop-up?

Comment: You can get the ids easily in the shell, go to the project directory and type 'git log', I think maybe you are used to UI interface, for git shell is more suit for me, you can try it.

Comment: You don't need to copy the entire sha. Use the command `git log --oneline`. This should provide an easy visualization with the "short" sha of each commit. Should be easier to handle also from the command line.

Comment: Shalen is right, oneline log is more convenient, with the same power.

Answer (score 1):

I think that `git checkout` should be your friend.

After cloning the repository you can do

```
git checkout -B master shainitialcommit
```

To reset the branch `master` to that commit. Then you can checkout every following commit in a similar way.

If you just want to see the changes commit by commit (and not, say, interact with the code), there are many diff tools that allows to do that (or you could use

Answer (score 1):

Try to use:

`git log --reverse`

It will show you the first commit at the top. Then you can just checkout at the first commit or just check how the commit looks:

`git show <hash_id>`